# Does Python's os.system() wait for an end of the process?

Tags: python

The [Python manual](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) says nothing about whether `os.system("cmd")` waits or not for a process to end:

To quote the manual:

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.

It looks like it does wait (same behaviour as Perl's `system`). Is this correct?

Comment: Successfully waits when tested with Ubuntu 20.04 Python 3.8.5 ```import os 
os.system('echo $(pwd); sleep 5')```

Comment: to just be sure, i make a bash script file with and wait statement at end and then in python run "os.system("bash myscript.sh"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes it does.  The return value of the call is the exit code of the subprocess.

Comment: Is this still true for py3.x? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059558/why-is-python-no-longer-waiting-for-os-system-to-finish

Comment: Yes, but people should not be using os.system at all. Use the subprocess package, probably one of the helper functions: call, check_call, check_output.

Comment: In python 3.5 call, check_call, and check_output have been replaced with the run function.

Comment: @RusselWinder: Why don't you add this to your answer? - explaining how one shoud use the subprocess package instead!

Answer (score 15):

The manual doesn't explicitly say, but it does imply that it waits for the end of the process by saying that the return value is the return value of the program.

So to answer your question, yes it does wait.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac it waits, but on Linux it does not (Debian, python 3.7.3).

Fixed using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("cmd")
```

Comment: Strange how, as a replacement, ```subprocess.run(['echo', '$(pwd)'])``` gives different output to  ```os.system('echo $(pwd)')```