# Python - Selenium: Problem of 'os.system' and 'driver.get()'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have problem of using selenium to open localhost:9222 with below code:

```
#-- IMPORT LIBRARY:
import time
import os
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

            

class TC_01_Start9222(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        #Step 1:
        vr_StartApp = os.system(r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/ABC/AppABC/AppABC.exe"')
                
        #Step 2:
        self.Driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.Driver.get("http://localhost:9222")
        print(self.Driver.title)
        vr_AppABC_GUI = self.Driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='items']/a[1]")
        vr_AppABC_GUI.click()

    def test_MainTC(self):
        pass
    
    def tearDown(self):       
        time.sleep(100)
        self.Driver.quit()


#-- REPORT BY UNITTEST-------------# 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
#----------------------------------#
```

With my code above:

- Step 1 can be run, AppABC can be started
- but Step 2: Chrome Browser cannot be start after that
- If I open AppABC manually (step 1), I Chrome Browser (Step 2) can be started completely

Can I ask if there is any problem when combining "os.system" and "driver.get()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you see might be related to the timing between starting the AppABC.exe and launching the Chrome browser.

When you use os.system, [it may not wait for the application to fully start before moving on to the next step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059558/why-is-python-no-longer-waiting-for-os-system-to-finish)

I suggest you to try to get rid of os.system (i.e. try to replace it with a subprocess) or add some sleep (time.sleep) between launching your app and the browser.